# Git bundler conflicts in gemlock with aptana

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict, gemfile.lock

How can I resolve conflicts like

```
-BUNDLED WITH
-   1.10.6
```

In my gemlock file everytime when I take pull and merging into some other branch.

It also abort stash applying before that.

Answer (score 0):

I got only one solution: just stage the conflict file and apply stash .Then you need to unstage it as modified stuff.